# NFS between two Ubuntu PCs

Tags: nfs

I hope anybody can shed some light on what I am doing with nfs. The instructions I have found on many different sites seem clear, but I cannot create the mount on the client side (192.168.1.25).

Here is what I have on the server 192.168.1.27 export file

```
/home 192.168.1.27(rw)
/var/nfs 192.168.1.27(rw)
```

on the server `/home` is `geppo:geppo`, while `/var/nfs` is `nobody:nogroup`

after creating the shares on the export file, I typed `exportnfs -a` and restarted the service nfs

the client is 192.168.1.25

if I type  `sudo showmount -e 192.168.1.27` from client this is what I see

```
Export list for 192.168.1.27:
/var/nfs 192.168.1.27
/home    192.168.1.27
```

now, if I type

```
$ sudo mount -vt nfs 192.168.1.27:/var/nfs /mnt/nfs/var/nfs
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Oct  8 07:38:13 2017
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.27,clientaddr=192.168.1.25'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.27:/var/nfs
```

or

```
$ sudo mount -v -t nfs 192.168.1.27:/home /mnt/nfs/home
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Oct  8 07:39:16 2017
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.27,clientaddr=192.168.1.25'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.27:/home
```

I do not understand since `/mnt/nfs/home` is owned by `geppo:geppo` and 
`/mnt/nfs/var/nfs` is owned by `nobody:nogroup`, in other words, the same permission should apply on both the server and the client

furthermore I have ufw enable on both server and client server, but if I type sudo ufw status on each of them I have the following

```
Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.1.25 - from server side
Anywhere                   ALLOW       192.168.1.27 - from client side
```

meaning there is no firewall on any port between the two

I must be doing something basically wrong, since I cannot figure out why I have the permission denied error... any clues?

Comment: Could be any number of problems. Start by disabling ufw on both machines and mount the nfs share on the server. If it does not mount on the server then it is a problem with server configuration and may be apparmor, check the server logs for both nfs and apparmor.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I just tried, but it looks like that even with the disabled firewall on both pc, the issue still remains. Where can i check for those logs so that maybe the issues is reported with more details ? Thanks

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, I did try to mount on server and it works, so the issue must be on the client, where would you suggest to look next ? Thanks

Comment: can you post the commands you ran on both server and client. On the server run `sudo exportfs -a` and  on the client run `sudo showmount -e  192.168.1.27`

Comment: The UID and GID (numerical owner) of the share must be the same on the server and the client.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen.  On server sudo exportfs -a I see  :                                       
     exportfs: /etc/exports [3]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 
    'no_subtree_check' specified for export "192.168.1.27:/home".
    Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
    NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x

    exportfs: /etc/exports [4]: Neither 'subtree_check' or 
    'no_subtree_check' specified for export "192.168.1.27:/var/nfs".
    Assuming default behaviour ('no_subtree_check').
    NOTE: this default has changed since nfs-utils version 1.0.x

Comment: on the client if I run sudo showmount -e 192.168.1.27, I see the following Export list for 192.168.1.27:
/var/nfs 192.168.1.27
/home    192.168.1.27

Comment: UID and GID are the same on both client and server 1000